# Adding a form inside tippy.js div (in node of cytoscape.js), but text input and buttons are not active

Tags: html, forms, tooltip, cytoscape.js

I have a cytoscape.js graph, and in each node i added a tippy.js tooltip. Inside the tooltip i have a form with a text input. Everything appears fine but text input and button inside the tooltip are not active.

I have changed z-index of div so that should be over cytoscape canvas. Still no success.

```
        var makeTippy = function (node, text) {

            return tippy(node.popperRef(), {
                    content: function () {
                            var div = document.createElement('div');
                            div.innerHTML = '<form name="input" >' +
                                                'For :  '+ node._private.data.name+'<br>'+
                                                'Value :<br>'+
                                                '<input type="text" name="value"><br>'  +                       
                                                '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />' +
                                                '</form>';
                            div.style.width = "100px";
                            div.style.height = "120px";
                            //div.style.background = "black";
                            div.style.color = "white";
                            div.style.position= "relative";
                            div.style.zIndex = "1500";                  
                            return div;
                    },
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    arrow: true,
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    hideOnClick: false,
                    multiple: true,
                    followCursor: true,
                    theme: 'run', 
                    sticky: true
                });

        };
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally it worked by setting interactive to true for the tippy instance:

interactive: true,